# Trying to Enter DateTime Data into Date Column, Date data is in two different formats

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_test 
(     
    customer_Id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    DOB DATE NULL DEFAULT '01-01-1970',    
    Gender NVARCHAR(250) NULL, 
    city_code NVARCHAR(250) NULL
)    

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_test (customer_Id, DOB, Gender, city_code)  
VALUES (270181, '01/10/1970', 'F', 2),
       (268073, '01/11/1970', 'M', 1),
       (273216, '15-01-1970', 'F', 5)
```

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Request you to remove ** from your statement first, there is not need to show in bold here or is this something else?

Comment: You need to do some ETL process to convert data in one format either date or month first because 04/03/2019 here month can be 04 or 03 so it will be confusing to you.

Comment: You should use the **ISO-8601** format for dates as string literals: `YYYYMMDD` - no dashes or any other delimiting characters - just the numbers - e.g. `19701001`, ? 19700115` etc. those are independent of any language/regional settings in your SQL Server

Comment: Are you typing in these date values or are you getting them from "somewhere"? Can you convert to a single format there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert `varchar` to `Date` along with `REPLACE` by this way

```
CONVERT(datetime, REPLACE('01/11/1970', '/', '-'), 103)
```

Live demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/36ac6/1)

Output

```
customer_Id     DOB        Gender   city_code
270181      1970-10-01        F      2
268073      1970-11-01        M      1
273216      1970-01-15        F      5
```

Comment: How you can insert 15-01-1970 into date column in your case. The two lines of insert in case of OP already working fine.

Comment: `convert(datetime,'15-01-1970',103)`

Comment: I've just updated my answer, pls take a look @Suraj Kumar

Comment: Does this answer your question? Pls let me know if you need any help. @Dhruv Nautiyal

Comment: i have 27000 such entries where dates are in two diff format as 15/01/1970 and 15-01-1970 i need one syntax for all

Comment: You can combine with  `REPLACE('15/01/1970', '/', '-')`

Comment: I've just updated my answer, Pls take a look  @Dhruv Nautiyal
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/36ac6/1

Comment: @DhruvNautiyal You should accept the answer as it was useful this is the return of the community member by you.